# How to unlock Microsoft Authenticator

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication

When I start Microsoft Authenticator, the message 'Authenticator locked' appears
When I press Unlock, the Verify Identity screen displays Unlock to continue.
What should I enter here and what should I do to know this code?

Did I forget something when setting it up, I cannot find anything about it in the documentation?
Thank you very much if you want to help me.

pm
I have translated the text of the messages into English and can therefore differ slightly.

Comment: After i added this comment I saw that you had already posted a question in the forum. I think this is a question for microsoft support. Send them a message on twitter or add a question in their forum. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?forum=MicrosoftAuthenticatorApp.

Comment: Have you tried entering your phones security code? I.e. Screen lock code.

Comment: Bingo, Johan thank you very much. In the setup of the App you can define App-lock, this mean that screenlock required when you open the App.
Never in the documentation I could thind this.